# Git works in cmd , but not in powersehll

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to use `git --version` in powershell but it doesn't execute the command, instead it opens a window asking how I want to open this file.

If I try to run it in cmd it works

Already tried to uninstall git, installed, and not functional.
I've also tried changing the environment variables, but to no avail.

Comment: What does it say in PS when you do `echo $env:PATH`? (Or specifically, is your `git` PATH in there)

Comment: @MikeKim yes, there is the 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;' and 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\;'

Comment: I managed to solve it, for some reason there was a file called git, without extension, in system32, that's why it was giving error. After deleting it all went well.